# I dont know how coursera inputs a list

Tags: python

[image: Coursera Image]

I have the assignment detailed in the image. The course has a place where you put the formula and it runs it and checks if it's correct. The problem is that it inputs a list which I don't know how to reference. Here is my formula:

```
def stats():
  # Output the list that the global identifier
  # my_list is bound to and the mean and
  # the population standard deviation of the
  # numbers in the list, rounded to two decimal
  # places.
   
    print(list1)
    my_list=float(sum(list1) / len(list1))
    print("mean is " + str(my_list))
    variance = (sum((x-(sum(list1) / len(list1)))**2 for x in list1) / (len(list1)))**0.5
    print("population standard deviation is "+ str(round(variance,2)))
list1=input()
```

I tried putting `input()` but it doesn't work. I also tried putting the input argument inside the def.

Comment: It looks like `my_list` _is_ the input.

Comment: As far as I can tell the list will be available as a global variable called `my_list`. You can just use it and don't have to use `input()`.

Comment: Yep my_list was the input, thanks guys